# Module classes not accessible in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-injection, module, dependencies

Before anyone marks this question as a duplicate, please note that i had tried all the solutions provided on other similar questions and none of them worked in my case.

I just added a module to my project and it is visible in the project view but the code is not accessible in parent module in which i had added it. 
[image]

and checking available options it is suggesting me to add dependency but its already added.

[image]

I had added the module dependency in gradle files also.

[image]

[image]

Also the reason why i had added the configuration in :

```
    implementation project(path: ':two', configuration:'default')
```

is because it was giving the following errors when adding it normally : 
[image]

Can anyone help me out with the issue.

Comment: File->Project structure->dependecies->module
Do you find you module listed there if not please add

Comment: yes. it is listed there.